# Show December values in Excel pivot table when collapsed to "Year" level

Tags: microsoft-excel

My Excel data table shows the number of units of inventory at the end of each calendar month. It looks like this:

[image: Excel data table]

I would like to create a pivot table that shows the last (i.e., December) value when it is collapsed to the Year level, as shown below:

[image: Pivot Table]

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: I am using Excel version 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** *to show option with pivot table*

If you really want to create a Pivot table, you can

- Add a column of months (eg C2:=MONTH(A2)
- Create a pivot table with

  - Years => Rows
  - Units => Values
  - Month => Filter

[image]

- Then Filter the Pivot table for Month -- 12.

[image]

***Of course, you can get a similar result by adding the month column, and filtering on that in your original data!!!***

---

A more dynamic option would be to set up a table with a column of the years.

Then you can use the formula: *(where G2 = the year and `Table5` is your data table)*

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX((YEAR(Table5[Date])=H2)*Table5[Date]),Table5,2,FALSE)
```

and fill down.

[image]

Comment: Ron, I tried the first suggested option, and it did the trick - much appreciated!